# how to get multiple checkbox value through $_POST via email php

Tags: php, html, email

### My html form for checkbox

```
<form  method="POST" class="registrationForm" id="registrationForm" action="processmail.php">
   <input type="checkbox" name="Activity[]" value="value1"  /> value1 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Activity[]" value="value2"  /> value2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Activity[]" value="value3"  /> value3 <br>

    <input type="submit" id="sendMessage" name="sendMessage" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

### My processmail.php

```
$message .= "<table border='1'>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Field of Activity    </td>.  <td>".$_POST['Activity']."</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";
```

---

by using above syntax, it only shows "Array" as options for my Field of Activity field, plz help me get options separated with comma which are selected....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use PHP implode function:

http://php.net/function.implode

Replace the line

```
$message .= "<tr><td>Field of Activity    </td>.  <td>".$_POST['Activity']."</td></tr>";
```

with

```
$message .= "<tr><td>Field of Activity    </td>.  <td>".implode(',', $_POST['Activity'])."</td></tr>";
```

Also - to prevent potentially malicious users injecting html into your page by editing the checkbox values before submitting, use htmlentities as well to escape the data before you re-render it onto the page

```
$message .= "<tr><td>Field of Activity    </td>.  <td>".implode(',', array_map('htmlentities', $_POST['Activity']))."</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through the values of the checkbox.

Right now, its getting an array instead of string.

Therefore, it printing as `Array`.

You can do it so by:

```
<?php
$ActivityStr = '';
if (isset($_POST['checkboxName']) && count($_POST['checkboxName']) > 0) {
    $i=0;
    foreach ($_POST['checkboxName'] as $cbox) {
        if ($i>0){
            $ActivityStr .= ',';
        }
        $ActivityStr .= $cbox;
        ++$i;
    }
}
$message .= ""; $message .= "Field of Activity ".$ActivityStr."";
$message .= "";
?>
```

Comment: Consider adding a comma or some such between elements. And why do you concatenate with empty strings? But yes this is the right approach.

Comment: Yes, I will consider commas.

Comment: See below answer - implode is designed for exactly this - no need to foreach over the results.

Answer (score 0):

The selections are in an array - one element for each option selected. You can use a `foreach` to loop over these elements and display them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to figure it out.

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

or even if you don't know if its a POST or a GET.

```
<?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?>
```

Anyways it's a array I guess you could use `foreach()`

```
foreach($_POST['Activity'] as $value) {
    echo "value is $value";
}
```

Comment: Why if he is converting array to string thats why has that

Comment: This is what I would do to discover the format then split it after I know how it's structured.

Comment: YEs but it obvious since in html if you check it you will see that checkboxes will come as an array...

Comment: I guess you are right but this is how I check how PHP reads the form variables. I never could remember them all :P, okay this isn't a good answer I should of posted it as a comment.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat That's nice I never used a IDE for PHP always was a notepad guy haha, thanks for that.

Comment: :) only not pad only hardcore :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$message .= "<tr><td>Field of Activity    </td>.  <td>".$_POST['Activity']."</td></tr>";
```

TO

```
$message .= "<tr><td>Field of Activity    </td>.  <td>".implode(',',$_POST['Activity'])."</td></tr>";
```